# Dynamic Condense List to ignore blanks and spaces

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a formula that can be used to analyse an array (say A1:A10) and return a condense list of that same array but remove all blank cells? The only caveat is, every cell in range A1:A10 is a formula, with some resulting in "", which are visually blank but obviously the cell itself contains a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot, the data in A1 is a formula `=IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),ROW(),"")` so every other row will evaluate to an empty string.

The formula in C2 is the array formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$10<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Array formulas must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, unless you have an Excel version with the new Dynamic Arrays formulas.

[image]

Comment: Perfect stuff. I am in the process of studying the formula right now, but it works great!